# 802.11g USB wireless adapter with Linux AP support

Tags: linux, usb, wireless-networking, embedded

Are there any USB wireless adapters out there that support 802.11g in AP mode under Linux?
Binary drivers are a no-go, as I plan to use it with an ARM device. Support for WPA would be very desirable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Linksys WUSB54G is supported by [prism54](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/p54#working), which claims to support AP mode, so I'll give that a shot. Moshen pointed me to linux-drivers.org, which pointed me in the right direction.

---

**Update**:

The WUSB54G has multiple variants, not all of which are supported by prism54. I ended up finding a Netgear WG121, which worked nicely through prism54.

Answer (score 2):

Try a [D-Link](http://www.dlink.com/category/productcategories/?cid=1) device.  They have an excellent record of using Atheros chipsets with superb linux compatibility.

Try looking on [Linux-Drivers.org](http://www.linux-drivers.org/network.html) for compatible hardware.

Comment: I looked at the D-link products at http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/products/laptops#D-Link but they all seem to be PCMCIA or PCI interfaces - unfortunately the device I plan to use it with has only a USB interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [TP-Link device](http://www.tp-link.com/products/product_des.asp?id=183) with an Atheros chipset (which I believe all their devices use). Plug 'n play :)

**Looks like I was wrong on this one (see comments)**

Comment: And it supports access point mode under linux?

Comment: I've only used it once as an AP to test, but it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Your asking made me second guess myself, so I dragged out the adapter and I couldn't get it into master mode. I'll let you know if I manage it, but at this stage it looks like I was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about non-x86 support, but I could get a ralink PCI card to work in Master Mode very easily (after a lot of previous attempts). I've posted the details in [my blog](http://my.opera.com/CrazyTerabyte/blog/2009/10/23/wi-fi-with-master-mode-finally).

I know that USB ralink cards are more trickier to work in Master Mode, and I don't know the current status for USB cards, but you might check the [rt2x00 project forum](http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com/phpBB/).

So, besides **prism54**, you might also try **ralink** (*rt2x00* driver) devices.

Answer (score -1):

Using Atheros USB devices in AP mode you'll be limited to 7 or 8 connected stations.